# Parsing JSON and exploring relationships in Python

Tags: python

**Question**:

> Given two users say user1 and usern, print True if there was a chain
>   of tweets such that user1 tagged user2, user2 tagged user3 .....
>   usern-1 tagged usern or viceversa.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The 1st line and the 2nd line contains the two users. The 3rd line of
>   the input contains the filename in which the dataset of tweets in JSON
>   format.
>
> **JSON Format**
>
> { "TweetCount" : 1, "TwitterData" : [ { "userName" : "user1",
>   "tweetid" : 12345, "tweet" : "@user2" } ] }
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print "True" ( quotes are for clarity ) if the two mentioned users are
>   connected, and "False" otherwise.
>
> **Constraints**:
>
> 1 <= TweetCount <= 300000
>   Username, Tweet are of UTF-8 format
>   1 <= Tweetid <= 10<sup>20</sup>
>
> **Sample Input**:
>
> ```
> user1
> user2
> input000.in
> ```
>
> **input000.in**
>
> { "TweetCount" : 2, "TwitterData" : [ { "userName" : "user1",
>   "tweetid" : 1, "tweet" : "Tweet 1 @user2" }, { "userName" : "user2",
>   "tweetid" : 2, "tweet" : "Tweet 2 @user4" } ] }
>
> **Sample Output:**
>
> True
>
> **Explanation**:
>
> user1 has user2 tagged in his tweet, hence True

I was wondering if you could take a look at my code and see if

1. there's a better way of solving the problem than the way I did it (i.e. should I construct a graph?)
2. I make my code more pythonic

```
import json

# standardize all input names to lower case
user1 = raw_input().lower()
user2 = raw_input().lower()

filename = raw_input()
user1_mentions = []
to_explore = []
reached = [] # list of users reached

with open(filename) as f:
    json = json.load(f) # JSON representation of input file

# find user1's mentions
for tweet in json['TwitterData']:
    if tweet['userName'] == user1:
        user1_mentions += ([x[1:].encode('utf-8') for x in tweet['tweet'].split() if x.startswith('@') and x[1:].isalnum()])
        to_explore = user1_mentions

while to_explore != []:
    temp_to_explore = [] # temp array for storing words to explore next
    for tweet in json['TwitterData']:
        if tweet['userName'] in to_explore:
            temp_to_explore += ([x[1:].encode('utf-8') for x in tweet['tweet'].split() if x.startswith('@') and x[1:].isalnum()])
    reached += to_explore
    to_explore = temp_to_explore

print reached # ['user2', 'user4']
print user2 in reached # True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Writing pythonic code**

Python has a coding guideline called [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It contains a lot of relevant information about how to write your code. You'll find various tools to check your code againt PEP 8 to ensure you follow it properly.

Among other things :

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty
>   sequences are false.

In your case, you should write `while to_explore` instead of `while to_explore != []`.

**A bit of scafolding**

In order to improve your code, it is a good thing to split it into different parts. Here I have splitted your code into functions. I took this chance to move the part calling functions behind an `if main` guard. Also, I have hardcoded some values to make testing easier. To make things better, the different functions should be documented but I can't be bothered.

```
import json

def get_input_data(from_user = False):
    if from_user:
        # standardize all input names to lower case
        user1 = raw_input().lower()
        user2 = raw_input().lower()
        with open(raw_input()) as f:
            json_data = json.load(f) # JSON representation of input file
    else:
        user1 = 'user1'
        user2 = 'user2'
        json_data = json.loads('{ "TweetCount" : 1, "TwitterData" : [ { "userName" : "user1", "tweetid" : 12345, "tweet" : "@user2" } ] }')
    data = json_data['TwitterData']
    return (user1, user2, data)


def chain_exists(user1, user2, data):
    user1_mentions = []
    to_explore = []
    reached = [] # list of users reached

    # find user1's mentions
    for tweet in data:
        if tweet['userName'] == user1:
            user1_mentions += ([x[1:].encode('utf-8') for x in tweet['tweet'].split() if x.startswith('@') and x[1:].isalnum()])
            to_explore = user1_mentions

    while to_explore != []:
        temp_to_explore = [] # temp array for storing words to explore next
        for tweet in data:
            if tweet['userName'] in to_explore:
                temp_to_explore += ([x[1:].encode('utf-8') for x in tweet['tweet'].split() if x.startswith('@') and x[1:].isalnum()])
        reached += to_explore
        to_explore = temp_to_explore

    print reached # ['user2', 'user4']
    return user2 in reached

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user1, user2, data = get_input_data()
    print(chain_exists(user1, user2, data))
```

It could be interesting to add more hardcoded tests.

**A bit of logic**

Everytime you add something to `user1_mentions`, you change `to_explore`. It probably would make sense to get the value at the end of the loop.

```
# find user1's mentions
for tweet in data:
    if tweet['userName'] == user1:
        user1_mentions += ([x[1:].encode('utf-8') for x in tweet['tweet'].split() if x.startswith('@') and x[1:].isalnum()])
to_explore = user1_mentions # this doesn't need to be defined before this point
```

**The right data structure**

The way you build `user1_mentions`, it might contain the same value multiple times. It is something we might want to avoid because it will not bring anything except performance issues. Instead of using list, you should use sets.

```
def chain_exists(user1, user2, data):
    user1_mentions = set()
    reached = [] # list of users reached

    # find user1's mentions
    for tweet in data:
        if tweet['userName'] == user1:
            user1_mentions.update([x[1:].encode('utf-8') for x in tweet['tweet'].split() if x.startswith('@') and x[1:].isalnum()])
    to_explore = user1_mentions

    while to_explore:
        temp_to_explore = set() # temp set for storing words to explore next
        for tweet in data:
            if tweet['userName'] in to_explore:
                temp_to_explore.update([x[1:].encode('utf-8') for x in tweet['tweet'].split() if x.startswith('@') and x[1:].isalnum()])
        reached += to_explore
        to_explore = temp_to_explore

    print reached # ['user2', 'user4']
    return user2 in reached
```

**The very right data structure**

In order to use to implement efficient algorithm, you'll need to preprocess your data into something relevant. Mapping user names to the set of users they mention is likely to be required. Here's a piece of code to do so :

```
def make_graph_from_data(data):
    graph = {}
    for tweet in data:
        graph.setdefault(
            tweet['userName'],
            set()).update(x[1:] for x in tweet['tweet'].split() if x.startswith('@') and x[1:].isalnum)
    return graph
```

Once you have the data preprocess, you won't need to worry about parsing tweets or whatever.

**A simple bug**

What if a user was to mention hisself ? You'd get stuck in the loop.

**Conclusion**

You'll find various solutions to your problem in the litterature so I'll let you have a look at this : it might be a good idea to consider solutions to [the shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) by considering a graph : you are in a case of [Directed graphs with nonnegative weights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Directed_graphs_with_nonnegative_weights). There might be some even more relevant algorithm because you care about the existence of a chain but not so much about it length but I don't have a particular algorithm in mind.